# Поиск и замена в файле с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, qregexp

Собственно сабж. Есть много файлов .срр в который очень много блоков кода  вида:

```
Application->MessageBox("Текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox("Другой текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox("Совсем другой текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
```

с очень большим вложением. Суть в чем. Необходимо преобразовать файлы в следующий вид:

```
Application->MessageBox(L"Текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Совсем другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
```

То есть добавить L перед каждой открывающей кавычкой строковой константы.
В [редакторе регулярных выражений](https://regex101.com/) методом проб и ошибок составил РВ:

```
regex = r"(\bApplication->MessageBox[AW]?\()([^\,]+\,)([^\,]+\,)(\bMB_OK\)\;)"
```

Решил делать все на питоне, вот мои соображения:

```
currFile = open("C:/test.cpp","r") )
currLine = currFile.read()
print(currLine)
print("\n\n\n")
matches = re.finditer(regex,currLine)
for match in matches:
    subst = match.group(1)+ "L" + match.group(2)+ "L" + match.group(3) + match.group(4)
    result = re.sub(regex,subst, currLine,0)
    print(result)
currFile.close()
```

Сейчас он находит на 1 итерации все вхождения, и тут же все меняет, на второй опять все меняет, и так пока не дойдет до последней, получаем:

```
Application->MessageBox(L"Совсем другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Совсем другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Совсем другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
```

Вот только не могу понять как с этим бороться.Необходимо сохранить оригинальный текст. Мб я не совсем корректно составил РВ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с этой регуляркой:

```
import re

text = """\
Application->MessageBox("Текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox("Другой текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox("Совсем другой текст.","Внимание",MB_OK);
"""

new_text = re.sub(
    r'Application->MessageBox\("(.+)","(.+)",MB_OK\);', 
    r'Application->MessageBox(L"\1",L"\2",MB_OK);', 
    text
)
print(new_text)
```

Консоль:

```
Application->MessageBox(L"Текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
Application->MessageBox(L"Совсем другой текст.",L"Внимание",MB_OK);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное) есть какие ресурсы для повышения понимания РВ и то как их составлять?

Comment: хмм, странно, попробовал на тестовом файле для примера, все норм,  попробовал на рабочем, не меняет

Comment: Может это быть связанно с размерами файла? от 40 до 60 файлов по 350+-кб это около 10к строк.

Comment: @dr_zak Не, с размерами тут явно нет проблем. Попробуйте только на одном рабочем файле проверить

Comment: то же самое. но я вроде как разобрался, иногда в перед "Внимание" и MB_OK есть пробел, по идее РВ подправил 
     Application->MessageBox[AW]?\("(.+)",[\s]?"(.+)",[\s]?MB_OK\);

Comment: @dr_zak, молодец что разобрались :)